# Getting Ansible example (jboss-standalone) to work with Vagrant

Tags: yaml, ansible, inventory

I need some assistance with getting https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples.git / jboss-standalone to work with Vagrant.  I think I am making the same mistake, with my Vagrant configuration.

My Vagrantfile is here:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "chef/centos-6.6"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.hostname = "webserver1"

  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
  ansible.verbose = "vvvv"
  ansible.inventory_path = "/Users/miledavenport/vagrant-ansible/jboss-standalone/hosts"
  end
end
```

My hosts file is here:

```
# Generated by Vagrant
default ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222

[jboss-servers]
webserver1

[webserver1]
127.0.0.1              ansible_connection=local



[localhost]
127.0.0.1
```

I am fairly new to using ansible, and want to "play" with Ansible, by using Vagrant.

"vagrant up" produces the following error:

```
TASK: [jboss-standalone | Install Java 1.7 and some basic dependencies] ******* 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

"vagrant ssh" works OK.

site.yml is:

```
---
# This playbook deploys a simple standalone JBoss server.

- hosts: jboss-servers
user: root

roles:
  - jboss-standalone
```

I don't understand why I am getting the error:
    FATAL: no hosts matched

The hosts contains webserver1, which is the same as the Vagrantfile hostname.

Can someone please help me to resolve this error.

Thanks :)

Miles.

Comment: 1. Hope the indentation is correct in your site.yml, one you posted is wrong. 2. There doesn't seem to be anything else wrong with your code. Are you sure `ansible-palybook` uses the inventory (hosts) file you posted? You can check using `ansible-playbook -h`. Or use `-i` to explicitly pass the inventory file. 3. Your inventory file doesn't make sense `webserver1` is a host as well as a hostgroup. But it should've still worked as long as DNS resolves `webserver1`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your intent is to create a parent group called jboss-servers, with a subgroup called webserver1

Try changing `[jboss-servers]` to `[jboss-servers:children]`

This will make the group jboss-servers also contain 127.0.0.1 as its hosts, and your playbook should run. [Link to DOCS](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables)

At the moment since webserver1 does not have the KVP `ansible_ssh_host=<ip>` associated with it, it is just a hostname without an ip to connect to. Make it a subgroup of jboss-servers only if you dont have webserver1 mapped to some IP in your /etc/hosts file or something :)